# combinations totaling to sum

Tags: matlab, combinations, permutation

How would one go about generating a matrix with all the possible combinations of number totaling to a sum with repetition?

Basically, combinations of `x1`, `x2`, `x3` such that `x1 + x2 + x3 = n`.

For example: `n =3`

```
0 1 2 
0 2 1
1 0 2
1 2 0
1 1 1
```

Is there simple way of doing this using predefined Matlab functions?

I tried

```
n=6;
nchoosek(0:n,3)
```

which gives me

```
 0     1     2
 0     1     3
 0     1     4
 0     1     5
 0     1     6
 0     2     3
 0     2     4
 0     2     5
 0     2     6
 0     3     4
 0     3     5
 0     3     6
 0     4     5
 0     4     6
 0     5     6
 1     2     3
 1     2     4
 1     2     5
 1     2     6
 1     3     4
 1     3     5
 1     3     6
 1     4     5
 1     4     6
 1     5     6
 2     3     4
 2     3     5
 2     3     6
 2     4     5
 2     4     6
 2     5     6
 3     4     5
 3     4     6
 3     5     6
 4     5     6
```

How would one extract all rows that have the total equal to `n`?
I think linear indexing or `find` should make it possible, but I don't know how to go about that.

Regards

Comment: You'd use logical indexing: `result = c(sum(c,2)==n,:);`, where `c` is the result of `nchoosek`. But `nchoosek` won't do, as it does not give repetitions

Comment: The standard way to do this is to imagine placing two dividers into a row of 6 objects, to obtain 3 separate partitions.  So you're looking at permuting 8 things: combinations of the 6 objects and the 2 dividers.  You should be able to manipulate the results of e.g., `nchoosek(1:8, 2)` to give you what you need.  That's *much* more efficient than generating all combinations and choosing those with the correct sum.

Comment: E.g., here's the corresponding thing in Python: `[(a, b-a-1, 7-b) for a, b in itertools.combinations(range(8), 2)]`.  (I don't have Matlab available here to experiment with, but you or someone else may be able to translate this.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For concreteness, let's go with your example of 3 values adding up to 6.  The standard way to do this is to think of placing 2 'dividers' into a row of 6 identical 'objects':  those dividers then divide the objects into 3 groups, and you can read off the length of each group.  So all we need to do is enumerate all ways of placing those dividers.  You can use `nchoosek(1:8, 2)` for this:  each row of that matrix describes a division, by describing the positions of the 2 dividers amongst the `2 + 6 == 8` objects + dividers.

This is a more efficient approach than enumerating all triples of integers 0-6 and then picking out those that add to the correct total.

I don't really speak MATLAB, so the following is probably unidiomatic (and suggestions to improve it are welcome!), but something like this should work:

```
% Total we're aiming for.                                                             
n = 6;                                                                                
% Number of pieces to divide that total into.                                         
k = 3;                                                                                
% All possible placements of internal dividers.                                       
dividers = nchoosek(1:(n+k-1), k-1);                                                  
ndividers = size(dividers, 1);                                                        
% Add dividers at the beginning and end.                                              
b = cat(2, zeros(ndividers, 1), dividers, (n+k)*ones(ndividers, 1));                  
% Find distances between dividers.                                                    
c = diff(b, 1, 2) - 1
```

And here are the results, as provided by [this site](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php):

```
c =

   0   0   6
   0   1   5
   0   2   4
   0   3   3
   0   4   2
   0   5   1
   0   6   0
   1   0   5
   1   1   4
   1   2   3
   1   3   2
   1   4   1
   1   5   0
   2   0   4
   2   1   3
   2   2   2
   2   3   1
   2   4   0
   3   0   3
   3   1   2
   3   2   1
   3   3   0
   4   0   2
   4   1   1
   4   2   0
   5   0   1
   5   1   0
   6   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dec2base`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/dec2base.html) to generate all combinations with repetition, and [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) to keep only those with the desired sum:

```
n = 6;
m = 3;
c = dec2base(0:(n+1)^m-1,n+1,m)-'0'; %// generate combinations with repetition
result = c(sum(c,2)==n,:); %// keep those with desired sum. Logical indexing
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well!
But, shouldn't 
   `6 0 0` `0 6 0` and `0 0 6` also be included?

Comment: @Ash Sorry. Corrected. Please try now

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are describing permutations of [restricted integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_partitions#Restricted_partitions), though your example doesn't seem complete.  For n=3 into three parts from elements {0, 1, 2} there are two solutions: {0, 1, 2} and {1, 1, 1}.  These may further be permuted into:

```
{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

If this is not what you want you should clarify why these additional orderings are not to be included.

If this understanding is correct you should be able to find a number of resources by searching for that phrase.  Some examples:

[Elegant Python code for Integer Partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10035752/618728)

[Integer Partition in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7515430/618728)

[Algorithm for generating integer partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18659/9909)

[Integer Partition Algorithm by Jerome Kelleher](http://homepages.ed.ac.uk/jkellehe/partitions.php)

[Integer Partition Algorithm by Daniel Scocco](http://www.programminglogic.com/integer-partition-algorithm/)

[Fast Algorithms for Generating Integer Partitions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.42.1287&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (PDF) (looks heavy-duty)

[Stony Brook Algorithm Repository - Partitions](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/generating-partitions.shtml)

As a practical example, using *Mathematica* one would write:

```
IntegerPartitions[6, {3}, Range[0, 5]]
```

Output:

> ```
> {{5, 1, 0}, {4, 2, 0}, {4, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 0}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}
> ```

These could each then be permuted to produce the other orderings.

It is quite easy to set up a recursive function to generate these partitions by starting with all numbers <= *n*, then appending values that are <= that value that do not exceed *n*.  This is continued until each list is length *p*; if the list totals `n` it is kept; if it does not it is discarded.  Again, in *Mathematica*:

```
f[n_, p_, c__] /; Length@{c} == p := If[+c == n, {{c}}, {}]
f[n_, p_, c___] := Array[f[n, p, c, #] &, Min[c, n - +c] + 1, 0, Join]

f[6, 3]
```

Output:

> ```
> {{2, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 0}, {4, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 0}, {5, 1, 0}, {6, 0, 0}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The function nchoosek provides the possible ways of selecting r-1 plus signs in the sum. For example, x1 + x2 + x3 = 5, then two signals must be selected over the sum 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5. For nonnegative solutions make the transformation yi = x1 + 1, and solves y1+y2+ ... = m + n

The result of nchoosek provides the position of the plus sign.

The remaining of program provides the sum between selected signals.

```
clear all    
close all    
clc    

% Program that generates the possible distributions
% M objects in r boxes 
% Éderson D'Martin Costa    
% 12/02/2015    

% number of objects
m = 3;    

% number of boxes    
r = 3;

% total number of possibilities
% C = nchoosek(m+r-1,r-1)

v = 1:m+r-1;    
C = nchoosek(v,r-1);    
[l,c] = size(C);    
Y = zeros(l,c+1);    
Y(:,1) = C(:,1);    
Y(:,end) = m+r-C(:,end);

for i = r-1:-1:2    
    Y(:,i) = C(:,i)-C(:,i-1);    
end    

X = Y-1;    
display(X)    
% sum(X,2)
```

Comment: Please translate it to english and/or add proper explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mark Dickinson pointed out. I just wanted to give intuitive explanation.

Your problem can be restated as "How many ways can you distribute 3 apples to 3 people"?

Suppose you have 3 people: AA, BB, CC and you want to distribute 3 apple among them. How can you do it?

```
AA   |    BB     | CC
***  |           | 
*    |     *     | *
**   |     *     | 
........
* -> represent apples.
```

Now if you think the problem is just selecting two `|` among 5 positions which we know can be done using 5 choose 2.