# MATLAB: efficient generation of a large integer matrix of multi-indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Let d and p be two integers. I need to generate a large matrix A of integers, having d columns and N=nchoosek(d+p,p) rows. Note that nchoosek(d+p,p) increases quickly with d and p, so it's very important that I can generate A quickly. The rows of A are all the multi-indices with components from 0 to p, such that the sum of the components is less than or equal to p. This means that, if d=3 and p=3, then A is an [N=nchoosek(3+3,3)=20x3] matrix with the following structure:

```
A=[0 0 0;
   1 0 0;
   0 1 0;
   0 0 1;
   2 0 0;
   1 1 0;
   1 0 1;
   0 2 0;
   0 1 1;
   0 0 2;
   3 0 0;
   2 1 0;
   2 0 1;
   1 2 0;
   1 1 1;       
   1 0 2;   
   0 3 0;      
   0 2 1;
   0 1 2;
   0 0 3]
```

It is not indispensable to follow exactly the row ordering I used, although it would make my life easier (for those interested, it's called graded lexicographical ordering and it's described here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order).

In case you are curious about the origin of this weird matrix, let me know!

Comment: Maybe [generate all possibilities (Cartesian product)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2586922) and then keep only those that meet the sum criterion?

Comment: As you say: The size of the matrix will grow pretty fast. Are you sure you need all the values simultaneously?

Comment: What are the actual sizes that you need to work with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [combinations totaling to sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500539/combinations-totaling-to-sum)

Comment: The possible duplicate provides a very clever approach that is way more efficient than all current solutions. It is not exactly the same, but you can get your matrix by concatenating multiple outputs of it.

Comment: @LuisMendo the number of rows for all possibilities grow exponentially with d, while nchoosek(d+p,p) grows polynomially, so creating the former and pruning is definitely not acceptable.

Comment: @knedlsepp, if I understand correctly your suggestion, I should use Mark Dickinson's answer in the other thread, for each i between 1 and p, and then concatenate the p matrices by row (together with the initial [0 0 0...0] row). On paper, this looks great because it doesn't involve generating even bigger matrices and then pruning. I'll try it out in MATLAB and let you know how it works.

Comment: @knedlsepp, Mark Dickinson's answer gives the rows in the opposite order to what I need. As I don't understand the code enough to change the ordering, I used `flipud` to solve, but if there's a way to get directly the ordering I need, without unnecessary flipping, please let me know. Also, how should I proceed now? I cannot choose Mark's as the answer to my question, since it's in another thread.

Comment: @DeltaIV: I flagged this post as a duplicate, so if the community considers it to be a duplicate this will be closed anyway. Otherwise I did reformulate my answer using *Mark*'s post, so you could also accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @knedlsepp it did solve my problem indeed! Thanks to you and all the others who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution using `nchoosek` and `diff`

The following solution is based on [this clever answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21501317/3139711) by *Mark Dickinson*.

```
function degrees = monomialDegrees(numVars, maxDegree)
if numVars==1
    degrees = (0:maxDegree).';
    return;
end
degrees = cell(maxDegree+1,1);
k = numVars;
for n = 0:maxDegree
    dividers = flipud(nchoosek(1:(n+k-1), k-1));
    degrees{n+1} = [dividers(:,1), diff(dividers,1,2), (n+k)-dividers(:,end)]-1;
end
degrees = cell2mat(degrees);
```

You can get your matrix by calling `monomialDegrees(d,p)`.

### Solution using `nchoosek` and `accumarray`/`histc`

This approach is based on the following idea: There is a bijection between all *k-multicombinations* and the matrix we are looking for. The multicombinations give the positions, where the entries should be added. For example the multicombination `[1,1,1,1,3]` will be mapped to `[4,0,1]`, as there are four `1`s, and one `3`. This can be either converted using `accumarray` or `histc`. Here is the `accumarray`-approach:

```
function degrees = monomialDegrees(numVars, maxDegree)
if numVars==1
    degrees = (0:maxDegree).';
    return;
end
degrees = cell(maxDegree+1,1);
degrees{1} = zeros(1,numVars);
for n = 1:maxDegree
    pos = nmultichoosek(1:numVars, n);
    degrees{n+1} = accumarray([reshape((1:size(pos,1)).'*ones(1,n),[],1),pos(:)],1);
end
degrees = cell2mat(degrees);
```

And here the alternative using `histc`:

```
function degrees = monomialDegrees(numVars, maxDegree)
if numVars==1
    degrees = (0:maxDegree).';
    return;
end
degrees = cell(maxDegree+1,1);
degrees(1:2) = {zeros(1,numVars); eye(numVars);};
for n = 2:maxDegree
    pos = nmultichoosek(1:numVars, n);
    degrees{n+1} = histc(pos.',1:numVars).';
end
degrees = cell2mat(degrees(1:maxDegree+1));
```

Both use the following function to generate multicombinations:

```
function combs = nmultichoosek(values, k)
if numel(values)==1
    n = values;
    combs = nchoosek(n+k-1,k);
else
    n = numel(values);
    combs = bsxfun(@minus, nchoosek(1:n+k-1,k), 0:k-1);
    combs = reshape(values(combs),[],k);
end
```

### Benchmarking:

Benchmarking the above codes yields that the `diff`-solution is faster if your `numVars` is low and `maxDegree` high. If `numVars` is higher than `maxDegree`, then the `histc` solution will be faster.

### Old approach:

This is an alternative to *Dennis'* approach of `dec2base`, which has a limit on the maximum base. It is still a lot slower than the above solutions.

```
function degrees = monomialDegrees(numVars, maxDegree)
Cs = cell(1,numVars);
[Cs{:}] = ndgrid(0:maxDegree);
degrees = reshape(cat(maxDegree+1, Cs{:}),(maxDegree+1)^numVars,[]);
degrees = degrees(sum(degrees,2)<=maxDegree,:);
```

Comment: Wow I didn't see your successive edits, where you compared the `diff` solution to the other ones. It's nice to know that there are other solutions which may be faster in some cases, but the `diff`  solution is already so much faster than any pruning-based solution, that I'm more than satisfied with using it in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it this way:

```
ncols=d;
colsum=p;
base=(0:colsum)';
v=@(dm)permute(base,[dm:-1:1]);

M=bsxfun(@plus,base,v(2));
for idx=3:ncols
    M=bsxfun(@plus,M,v(idx));
end
L=M<=colsum;
A=cell(1,ncols);
[A{:}]=ind2sub(size(L),find(L));
a=cell2mat(A);
%subtract 1 because 1 based indexing but base starts at 0
a=a-1+min(base);
```

It builds up a p-dimensional matrix which contains the sum. The efficiency of this code depends on `sum(L(:))/numel(L)`, this quotient tells you how much of the created matrix is actually used for solutions. If this gets low for your intput, there probably exits a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very easy way to do it:

```
L = dec2base(0:4^3-1,4);
idx=sum(num2str(L)-'0',2)<=3;
L(idx,:)
```

I think the first line can be very time efficient for creating a list of candidates, but unfortunately I don't know how to reduce the list in an efficient way after that.

So the second line works, but could use improvement performance wise.